# What are the relations between the level of power and abilities and the promotion of Pawn?

Tags: high-school-dxd

In chess, pawn can promote to any other chess piece except King and get all the corresponding abilities and power. Similarly, in High School DxD, when Pawn promotes, their power level increases and they get other abilities also. For example, when **Issei** got a direct hit from **Yubelluna**'s attack, he was protected by the **Queen Protection** abilities.

Let's take Issei's promotion to Queen (**Akeno**) as an example.

Are the abilities and the increase in power level the same for all the Pawns regardless of the power and abilities of the actual Queen (Akeno), or do they depend on that of the Queen?

And if Issei is King of his pieces and promotes himself to Queen, gaining abilities and power from both King and Queen pieces, will he be more powerful than Akeno?

Answer (score 1):

**No, the ability doesn't depend on the Queen of the group**. I forgot whether it was Rias herself, or Azazel-sensei that said that the stronger Issei is, the longer he can stay in promotion as the promotion takes its toll on his body. **If the promotion depends on the power of the team's Queen, then there won't be any need for Issei to improve his physical strength.**

In the light novel, it was explained that each piece has a value. Queen worth 9 pawn, Rook worth 5, Bishop and Knight 2. So, rather than the strength of the Queen, the promotion increases the strength according to those numbers, I think. Of course the improvement depends on which piece he's going to promote into.

For example, Knight is worth 2 Pawns, so the ability improvement is more or less 2x of his ability as Pawn. However, it is not distributed evenly. Most of it will be distributed to the Speed. Queen, being all-round piece, will get an even increment to all abilities.

Comment: Queen Protection is because of promotion or its akeno's power and according to your ans does it apply if it was not isse.

Comment: No, the ability doesn't depend on the Queen of the group. I think that's clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be certain because I haven't read the source material nor am I sure that the author took this into consideration, but if I were to theorise I'd say power was more related to the sacred gear and number of peices consumed in the creation. By this I mean since Issei consumed 8 pawns his promotion to queen should be, hypothetically 8 times as strong as the promotion of a single pawn. I don't think the strength of his queen would impact this, but I cant tell for sure how powerful shed be in comparison. The other thing to consider is the sacred gear. Issei's Welsh dragon is inconsistent with its power, and thus he may be weaker than a normal queen on no stacks but stronger after some. I'm not sure what you mean by the king of peices thing.

Comment: would you try to elaborate a bit more and answer with different paragraph so it will help me to understand what you are trying to say

Comment: _king of peices_ you mean last part of question.

Comment: Yeah, so essentially Issei consumed 8 pawns because of the nature of his sacred gear. Since the Welsh Dragon is such a powerful gear, it took all of Rias' pawns.

In chess terms, hypothetically 8 pawns can be promoted to make 8 queens, and it wouldn't be fair if each promotion was of equal power. Hence I believe that the power of said queen is directly proportional to the power of the pawn.

And yes, I'm not entirely sure what you mean in the last part of the question.

Comment: here issei is just for example as mentioned in question, i asking for general